# swift ios use image or UIView to display dummy placeholder until data has loaded

Tags: ios, swift, api, placeholder

If I click on an item in my tableView a new VC will open.

But I want to display a dummy placeholder and a loading indicator that disappears once the data has been fetched from my server.

But should I use and image as a placeholder or should I style a UIView? I dont know whats best memorywise

I want to show something like this:
[image]

Then make it fade away once the data has been fetched from my API.

Answer (score 0):

It is your choice. You know the viewcontroller lifecycle includes some methods for jobs like these. Like WievWillAppear, ViewDisappeared, ViewShouldAppear... But if you want to add an animation, you may style a view to show the animation like facebook.